# How to remove the horizontal line from the chapter title in thatcher using memoir

Tags: memoir, chapters, rules

I would like to remove the horizontal line between the Chapter Title and Number...

Here is my customized MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Define identação em todo primeiro parágrafo
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} %=========================================================================
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}}

    \chapter{First}
        \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Is there a way to remove the horizontal line?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\afterchapternum` to just issue a `\par`. By default it's defined as

```
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{%
    \par\centerline{\parbox{0.5in}{\hrulefill}}\par}
```

under the `thatcher` chapter style, which insert the 1/2" horizontal rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Werner.

Is there a way to have a bigger space between the number and the title name?

Comment: I thought of adding an extra `\bigbreak` or other vertical spacing command just after the `\par`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is....with a bigger space between title and number...I believe it is not going to cause any problem further ahead.

Just added the `\bigbreak` after `\par`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Define identação em todo primeiro parágrafo
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} %=========================================================================

    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\bigbreak}

    \chapter{First}
        \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```